# Replace custom validator in server side with client side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, active-directory

I have a server side customvalidator. Because it is not firing, so I want to use client side to validate a textbox. It include active directory something. I am not sure can we convert the code to client side?

```
<td class="style4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td><td><asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorUser" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextUserName"
                                ErrorMessage="Minimum of 6 (six) alphanumeric characters." 
                OnServerValidate="ValidateUser" Display="Dynamic"
                                ValidateEmptyText="True" ></asp:CustomValidator></td>
```

And

```
 protected void ValidateUser(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
 {
        string UserNameCreated = TextUserName.Text;
        string AD_Server = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_Server"];
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(AD_Server);
        entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" + UserNameCreated + "))";

        SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
        Match match = Regex.Match(args.Value, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (results.Count > 0)
            args.IsValid = false;
        else if (match.Success)
            args.IsValid = true;
        // true means that it is validated. 
        else
            args.IsValid = false;
 }
```

My thought:

Fist:

```
<td class="style4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td><td><asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorUser" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextUserName"
                                ErrorMessage="Minimum of 6 (six) alphanumeric characters." 
                ClientValidatationFunction="ValidateUser" Display="Dynamic"
                                ValidateEmptyText="True" ></asp:CustomValidator></td>
```

Second

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function ValidateUser(source, arguments)
{
    var RegularExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$/;
    if (arguments.Value.test(RegularExpression) == 0 ){
        arguments.IsValid = true;
    } else {
        arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Then how about AD? Maybe it is a wrong question!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exaclty how are you planning to use this code, if it's related to authentication in any aspect you should perform all validations on server side since client code can be easily cracked.

With this said, in case the security is not a problem, you could have a web method on the server to get results count. You would call this web method trough an ajax call.

Comment: Note that doing both is a good idea for certain validation. For instance required fields checked client side can produce quicker feedback.

Comment: @Guvante: I totally agree with you for cases where security is not a problem, but if you're trying to authenticate a user, you need to perform necessary actions on the server (except for empty field validations as you mention). Without more information from user is hard to say if client validation is suitable for this case.

Comment: Please give me an ajax call link. I may consider pure client side check or combining client side and server side.

Comment: @Love: are you using jquery on your project?

Comment: @Love: check this link http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Great! Could you please check my RegularExpression part? Is it correct?

Comment: @Love: your regex looks correct to me. Just remove `== 0` since `test` method returns `true` or `false`